# Python name mangling on global variable with __

Tags: python, cpython, name-mangling

When I created a module-level variable with `__` and tried to access it inside a method of a class (using `global` keyword) the name-mangling occured.

Let me show an example:

```
__test = 'asd'  # module level variable with __


class TestClass(object):
    def test(self):
        global __test
        print(__test)  # trying to access this variable


a = TestClass()
a.test()
```

Interpreter raised an error:

`NameError: name '_TestClass__test' is not defined`

So as we can see it tried to name-mangle `__test` into `_TestClass__test`.

I thought that name-mangling should be used only for class variables (when I access them with `self` or class name).

Is it a well-defined behaviour that I have not be aware of or it is some kind of Python bug?

I tested it on CPython 3.5

Comment: Why are you creating *"a module-level variable with `__`"*?

Comment: Note specifically, as quoted from the docs *"This mangling is done without regard to the syntactic position of the identifier"*

Comment: Actually one of mine students (I teaching python on some beginner level) did this and I was not sure why it haven't work for him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Any identifier** of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores,
>   at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with
>   `_classname__spam`, where `classname` is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done **without regard**
>   **to the syntactic position of the identifier**, as long as it occurs
>   within the definition of a class.

(from [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references), emphasis mine)

Comment: aww I should checked docs first :P

Comment: see: https://bugs.python.org/issue27793

I'd argue this is a bug, seeing one would reasonably expect that when using the `global` keyword explicitly, one would get the global variable. Even if it's documented its highly inconsistent and illogical.

Comment: @con-f-use It is philosophical question, whether a bug in specification is a bug. ;)
I agree that there may be a better way to avoid name clash with subclasses.

Comment: My issue is not really with a name clash but with `global` being the stronger "philosophical" concept because it is explicitly stated here. Also, to my knowledge there is no mention in the documentation of global about working everywhere **except** inside classes for variable names staring (but not ending) with `__`...

Comment: @con-f-use What I meant is that the sole purpose of name mangling I can see is to avoid name clashes in subclasses.